# Operator from vector space to Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let X be a linear space and Y be a Hilbert space.$ A:X \rightarrow Y$ be a linear operator.
Let $ S_{y} = \{x\in X : \left\Vert Ax-y\right\Vert  \leq \left\Vert Au-y\right\Vert  \forall u\in X\} $.
Show that $ S_{y}$ is non empty if and only if y$\in R(A)+ R(A)^\perp$.

If y$\in R(A)+ R(A)^\perp$ , $\exists$ v such that y=Av+k where k$\in R(A)^\perp$ its easy to show that $v\in S_{y}$.
If $S_{y}$ is non empty , Im not sure on how to proceed to show that $ y\in $ $R(A)+R(A)^\perp$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $\|Ax-y\|^{2} \leq \|A(u+tx)-y\|^{2}$ for al $t$, for all $u \in X$. Expanding this and  choosing  a suitable $t$ show that $ \langle (Ax-y), Au \rangle=0$. Since this is true for each $u$ we see that $Ax-y \in R(A)^{\perp}$. Finally, $y=Ax+(y-Ax)$ finisihes the proof.